# C++ shared_ptr<Base> pointer acces violation

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual, shared-ptr, radix

I'm using `shared_ptr<Base>` for some sort of tree list with derived classes. But I'm getting a pointer acces violation when my tree gets destructed.

My code looks something like this, besides, this actually similates my runtime error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


class Base;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> pBase;
class Derived;

class Base {
public:        
    std::vector<pBase> children;

    pBase parent;

    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual void doSomething() {}
    void add(pBase i);
};

class Derived : public Base {
    void doSomething() {
        // Do something...
    }
};

void Base::add(pBase i) {
    i->parent = pBase(this);
    children.push_back(i);
}


int main() {
    pBase tree = pBase(new Derived());
    pBase child(new Derived());
    child->add(pBase(new Derived()));
    tree->add(child);
}
```

Also when I add the following lines to `Base::~Base`:
    std::cout << "destruct " << name << std::endl;

And implement a std::string called name in `Base` which is different for each instance, I can see that the destructor is called multiple times (because of the `Base::parent` reference I think). That ofcourse triggered my error, but I still don't understand why it happens because `shared_ptr<Base>` is expected to count its references before actually destroying it!!?

I hope some can tell me what I'm doing wrong!
But more important, how I can fix this!

Comment: You did not initialize `tree`, among the other problems you have...

Comment: @ybungalobill I'm sorry, I can't see what you are refering too?

Comment: Because you fixed it after I pointed it out...

Comment: @ybungalobill I did, I mean `the other problems you have`?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this line in add()

```
i->parent = pBase(this);
```

Each time you call add, you're creating a *new* shared pointer to `this`. These shared pointer are separate - that is, they are *NOT* 'shared' as you think. So, the first time you delete a child, it's parent gets deleted (because it's a shared pointer). Hence your code blows up.

Try (as a start) making parent a plain dumb pointer.

```
Base *parent;
```

Comment: Thanks! That should be it!

Comment: I wouldn't advise mixing plain pointers and smart pointers together on one object. In the end, it may happen that the parent is deleted leaving the child with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the others' answers: The canonical way to do what you want in the line

```
i->parent = pBase(this);
```

is to use [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). You

1. Derive `Base` from it

   ```
   class Base : std::enable_shared_from_this<Base> {
   ```
2. Ensure that every `Base` instance is owned by a `std::shared_ptr`. That is OK in your case, since you create the objects in expressions like

   ```
   pBase child(new Derived());
   ```
3. Use `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` when you want a `std::shared_ptr`. The problematic line will then become

   ```
   i->parent = shared_from_this();
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this actually was the easiest way to solve it!:)
Edit: Is this a fast way compared to others, if it is used on a large scale?

Comment: @Tim: It should be about as fast as sebastian's, with slight space overhead.

Comment: Neat, and it looks like there's a boost equivalent which is even handier as I'm stuck without a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
i->parent = pBase(this);
```

you create a smart pointer from a plain old pointer to an object which you didn't get directly from new. Never do this.

As @Roddy explained, you get separate smart pointer objects, with separate reference counters. Two reference counters for one pointee won't work.

In your case, it's probably ok to make parent a normal pointer, as @Roddy proposed. This way, you don't get in trouble with cyclic references. Just be sure that you never access the parent pointer after you deleted the parent. No problem if you delete all the children together with the parent (which happens automatically, unless you store more smart pointers to them, somewhere else)

If you want to initialize a smart pointer, you've got two choices, basically: Use smart pointers in every interface. Unfortunately that doesn't work for "this" because that's an implicit parameter. You would need to pass the smart pointer, which you already created, to the method manually, in an extra parameter. Like this:

```
tree->add(tree, child);
```

Which is kind of ugly, so you may want to consider making "add" a static method, so you won't need to pass the parent twice.

The other choice: Use another kind of smart pointer, like boost::intrusive_ptr, where you can store the reference count in the pointee. This way, you are able to find the reference count, even if you've got only a dumb pointer like "this".

Edit: The answer by @jpalecek, below, is better. Use that one. Sebastian.